# How to swap the names and values of a named vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

I am interested in swapping the names and values of my vector

```r
y <- c(a = "Apple", b = "Banana")
```

I would instead like code that creates the equivalent of

```
y <- c(Apple = "a", Banana = "b")
```

I see there is the `invert` function in the the [`searchable` package](https://rdrr.io/cran/searchable/man/invert.html), but this doesn't seem like it's updated for Version 4 of R yet.

Comment: You can install the `searchable` package.  Please check my solution below

Comment: note for posterity: this question is related to names at values at the vector level. At the column level, you would use a very similar solution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337009/10952717 for useful information

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use :

```
setNames(names(y), y)
# Apple Banana 
#   "a"    "b"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `enframe/deframe`

```
library(tibble)
enframe(y) %>% 
    select(2:1) %>% 
    deframe
#  Apple Banana 
#  "a"    "b"
```

---

It is possible to install the package from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/searchable/).  Download the tar file in working directory, use `install.packages` with `local = TRUE`

```
install.packages("searchable_0.3.3.1.tar.gz", local = TRUE)
#inferring 'repos = NULL' from 'pkgs'
#* installing *source* package ‘searchable’ ...
#** package ‘searchable’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#** using staged installation
#** R
#** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
#** help
#*** installing help indices
#** building package indices
#** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
#** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
#** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
#* DONE (searchable)
```

Now, we can test it

```
library(searchable)
invert(y)
#  Apple Banana 
#   "a"    "b"
```